# How to convert an array to a list of strings during function call in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rrdtool, rrd

I'm trying to call `RRD.create` in Ruby. My RRD variables are stored in a hash and I need to construct an `RRD.create` call. Here is my code:

```
pool_map = {
  "cleanup"  => "Cleaning up",
  "leased" => "Leased",
  "ready"  => "Ready"
}

start = Time.now.to_i
ti = 60 # time interval, in seconds

RRD.create(
         rrdfile,
         "--start", "#{start - 1}",
         "--step",  ti, # seconds
         pool_map.keys.map{|val| "DS:#{val}:GAUGE:#{ti * 2}:0:U" }.collect,
         "RRA:LAST:0.5:1:#{86400 / ti}",         # detailed values for last 24 hours
         "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:#{5*60 / ti}:#{7*24*60}", # 5 min averages for 7 days
         "RRA:MAX:0.5:#{5*60 / ti}:#{7*24*60}",     # 5 min maximums for 7 days
         "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:#{60*60 / ti}:#{183*24}", # 1 hour averages for a half of the year
         "RRA:MAX:0.5:#{60*60 / ti}:#{183*24}"      # 1 hour maximums for a half of the year
        )
```

However, I'm getting the following error from Ruby:

```
in `create': invalid argument - Array, expected T_STRING or T_FIXNUM on index 5 (TypeError)
```

I need to specify a several strings to `RRD.create` instead of passing array. How can I do this in Ruby?

P.S. http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/rrdruby.en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the "splat" operator (unary asterisk):

```
*pool_map.keys.map{|val| ...}
```

Note that you don't need the `collect` at the end there, it does nothing! `collect` is just  an alias for `map`, and you aren't doing anything with it because you haven't passed it a block.

Splat is really useful for destructuring arrays:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = *arr
# a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
```

And you can often use it to supply arguments to methods, like you are trying to do

```
def sum_three_numbers(x, y, z)
  x + y + z
end

arr = [1, 2, 3]
sum_three_numbers(*arr)
# => 6

arr = [1, 2]
sum_three_numbers(100, *arr)
# => 103
```

Comment: I'd never though to use splat that way! (I've only really used it in method definition as in "unknown number of params in Array"). This is awesome, and I love Ruby even more then I previously did

Comment: Thanks a lot for splat operator suggestion! I've applied it but still have issues:

Comment: I've changed my line to `*pool_map.keys.map{|val| "DS:#{val}:GAUGE:#{ti * 2}:0:U" },` but still getting a lot of errors like `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting tAMPER`